# How do I print a triangle of stars using SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Is it practically possible to create a triangle of stars like this as below in SQL.I know that this could be done easily in any other programming language like C,C++,Java but want to know whether it is really possible with just SQL or PL/SQL.I tried working on it with dual table in Oracle but couldn't get through it.

```
  *              *
 * *             * * 
* * *    or      * * *
```

Can someone please shed somelight if anyone knows about it.

Comment: Yes it should be possible.  Is this just for fun or a real purpose?

Comment: SQL itself can't print anything, can it?

Comment: How is the height of the triangle specified?  How is it supposed to be returned, as a collection of rows, or a single field, etc.?

Comment: smells like homework! sorry if it isn't... ;)

Comment: I want it to be a generic.. If I want to print it for a length of 'n' how can I do it? Should I use 'n' number of SELECTS and union all of them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simplest approach would be something like this.  You can get more sophisticated particularly if you want to build the equilateral triangle rather than the right triangle.

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  select rpad( '* ', level*2, '* ' )
  2    from dual
  3* connect by level <= 3
SQL> /

RPAD('*',LEVEL*2,'*')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*
* *
* * *
```

Comment: This is the one I was looking for... Thank you.. But how about an equilateral triangle...?

Comment: Doesn't that query need an order by level to _guarantee_ that a triangle is produced?

Answer (score 5):

```
select rpad('* ', level * 2, '* ')
  from dual connect by
    level <= 10
* 
* * 
* * * 
* * * * 
* * * * * 
* * * * * * 
* * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * * 


select rpad(' ',r*2,' ')||rpad('* ',l*2,'* ') k 
  from ( select level l,row_number() over(order by null) r 
            from dual 
           connect by level<=10 
         order by l desc)

  * * * * * * * * * * 
    * * * * * * * * * 
      * * * * * * * * 
        * * * * * * * 
          * * * * * * 
            * * * * * 
              * * * * 
                * * * 
                  * * 
                    *



select rpad(' ',l*2,' ')||rpad('* ',r*2,'* ') k 
 from ( select level l,row_number() over(order by null) r 
          from dual 
         connect by level<=10 
         order by l desc)

                    * 
                  * * 
                * * * 
              * * * * 
            * * * * * 
          * * * * * * 
        * * * * * * * 
      * * * * * * * * 
    * * * * * * * * * 
  * * * * * * * * * * 

select rpad(' ',l,' ')||rpad('* ',r*2,'* ') k 
from ( select level l,row_number() over(order by null) r 
        from dual 
       connect by level<=10 
       order by l desc) 

      * 
     * * 
    * * * 
   * * * * 
  * * * * * 
 * * * * * * 
* * * * * * *
```

Comment: You might want to improve the formatting of your source code. Close to unreadable!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you are looking for exactly. Perhaps this?

```
select '*' from dual
union all select '**' from dual
union all select '***' from dual
```

[Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/302)

Comment: Doesn't fit if I have to print for large number of times e.g. 20.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the script to Get a perfect triangle or Pyramid in sql (tested in Microsoft Sql 2008)

```
declare @x int,@y int
select @x=5,@y=0
while @x>0
begin
print space(@x)+replicate('*',@y)+replicate('*',@y+1)
set @y=@y+1
set @x=@x-1
end
```

---

```
     *
    ***
   *****
  *******
 *********
```

you can get many more scripts and help at this link... it was helpful to me

Link:-  [sqlquerynscript](http://sqlquerynscript.blog.com/?s=triangle&submit=Search)

Comment: This isn't an Oracle-supported syntax.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this..**

```
 declare @x int,@y int,@diff int
 select @x=0,@y=10,@diff=2--diferrence between consecutive rows
 while @x<@y
 begin
    if @x=0 and @diff<>1
       print space((@y-@x)*@diff-1)+replicate('*',1)
    else if(@diff%2=0)
       print space((@y-@x)*@diff)+replicate('* ',@x+(@x*(@diff-1)))
    else
       print space((@y-@x)*@diff)+replicate('* ',@x+(@x*(@diff-1)))
    select @x=@x+1
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is the simple triangle, then you can do this:

```
SELECT '*' FROM table
UNION
SELECT '**' FROM table
UNION
SELECT '***' FROM table
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @count int,@num int,@num1 int, @space int, @str varchar(50)
set @count = 5 set @num = 1
while(@num<=@count)
begin
  set @num1 = 0 set @space = @count-@num
  while (@num1<@num)
  begin
   if @str is null
    set @str = '* '
   else
    set @str = @str+'* '   set @num1 = @num1+1
  end
print (space(@space)+@str)
set @num = @num+1   set @str = null
end
```

Answer (score 0):

[Equilateral Traingle] We can make a pyramid with Oracle SQL as follows.

```
select rpad(' ',5 -level) || rpad( '* ', level*2, '* ' )
   from dual
 connect by level <= 5;
```

** Here 5 is the number of lines.

Let us reverse it,

```
select rpad(' ',level) || rpad( '* ', 2*(5-level+1), '* ' )
  from dual
 connect by level <= 5;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
declare @row int = 5,
@index int = 0,
@string nvarchar(5) =''
while @row > 0
begin
    set @index = @row
    while @index > 0
    begin
        set @string = '*' + @string
        set @index = @index - 1
    end
    print @string
    set @string = ''
    set @row = @row - 1
end
```

> ```
>  *****
>  ****
>  ***
>  **
>  *
> ```

Comment: this seems to work but it require much effort to correct little syntax mistake. It took me a while to find out what was wrong with it to get a down vote if the star orientation didn't matter

Answer (score -1):

```
DECLARE @lclMaxLevel INT=5
DECLARE @lclPrintCount INT =0

WHILE @lclMaxLevel > 0
  BEGIN
      PRINT Space(@lclMaxLevel)
            + Replicate('*', @lclPrintCount+1)

      SET @lclMaxLevel=@lclMaxLevel - 1
      SET @lclPrintCount=@lclPrintCount + 1
  END
```