# Having a sequence of numbers, create a pyramid

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

Is it possible having a sequence of numbers e.g. :

> 1,2,3,4,5

to create / print a pyramid like:

> 1
>   1, 2
>   1, 2, 3
>   1, 2, 3, 4
>   1, 2, 3, 4, 5

This can be easily done with loop, however I would like to avoid them.

My solution until now is to create each line's select string dynamically and them `union` all the lines to get the desired result. For example:

```
-- @Line1 = '1, 
select @Line1 = coalesce(@Line1 + ',', '') + Num 
  from Numbers
 where Num < 2

-- @Line2 = '1, 2,'
select @Line2 = coalesce(@Line2 + ',', '') + Num 
  from Numbers
 where Num < 3

select @Line1
union
select @Line2
.
.
.
```

and the execute it. The code is not complete but I think it gives an idea on what I am trying.

Any ideas on how to improve it?

Related: [How do I print a triangle of stars using SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9930364/how-do-i-print-a-triangle-of-stars-using-sql)

Note: This may not have a real usage. I found this as an exercise in various languages and all propose a solution in loops. I thought it will be interesting to try it in SQL Server.

Comment: Why T-SQL and not a programming language?

Comment: @H.Pauwelyn I thought that it will be interesting to try something different than loops. Also tsql is a language I am using every day and I want to try my skills.

Comment: If you have a `Numbers` table you can perform an OUTER APPLY to get all previous numbers for eash. After that, you need some way to *concatenate* the strings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is relatively easy if you have :

- A [Numbers table](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1),ie a table that contains numbers from 1 to some large number and
- An aggregate function that can [concatenate rows](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/08/t-sql-queries/sql-server-grouped-concatenation). Such a function, `STRING_AGG`  will be added in the next version of SQL Server (ie the one *after* 2016). There are various techinques to create such a function. The linked article shows the various options, using SQLCLR, XML operators, CTEs, a cursor etc. The fastes method is SQLCLR.

Assuming the concatenation method is `GROUP_CONCAT()` you can write:

```
select o.n,dbo.GROUP_CONCAT_S(x.n) as Result
from numbers  o outer apply (select n from numbers i where i.n<=o.n) x
where o.n<=5
group by o.n
```

This will return:

```
n           Result
----------- ----------
1           1
2           1,2
3           1,2,3
4           1,2,3,4
5           1,2,3,4,5
```

Comment: All three answers are great. I am accepting this one, out of preference. IMHO is more compact and readable. Having the `numbers ` as an input, makes it less bounded to the specific problem. The only drawback is that I have to create the `GROUP_CONCAT_S` function.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
WITH Numbers AS 
(
    SELECT TOP 5 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS Nr 
    FROM master..spt_values
) 
SELECT STUFF(
            (
            SELECT ',' + CAST(x.Nr AS VARCHAR(10)) 
            FROM Numbers AS x 
            WHERE x.Nr<=Numbers.Nr
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ),1,1,''
            ) AS Result
FROM Numbers
```

The result

```
Result
1
1,2
1,2,3
1,2,3,4
1,2,3,4,5
```

Comment: *Interestingly, the limit you up to which you can use this is 2508.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu This is due to the values in `master::spt_values`... You might use a real *on the fly* tally table or just add a `CROSS JOIN master::spt_values AS x` to get a much bigger number... (The size of the target string matters too, of course...)

Comment: Ah, of course. Didn't think to do a select from `master..spt_values`. Great stuff @Shnugo!

Answer (score 2):

I place this as a second answer because this is a completely different approach:

A recursive CTE is nothing else then a *hidden RBAR* (so an *invisible loop*). but it is - well - uhm - more beautiful :-)

```
WITH recCTE AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS Nr, CAST('1' AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS concString
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT recCTE.Nr+1,concString + ',' + CAST(recCTE.Nr+1 AS VARCHAR(10))
    FROM recCTE
)
SELECT TOP 5 * FROM recCTE
```

Comment: I think also a litim here, for 'select top 102 * from recCTE', I end up with the error `The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.`. In any case a 'recursive CTE', is an interesting solution!

Comment: @Athafoud Google Formulare `maxrecursion`

Comment: Yeap! I already did this! I am just testing different scenarios, to see any limits.